# Imports from external styles sheet does not work angular

Tags: angular

I have external SASS file like external.scss and which has below content

```
@import "core/colors";
```

This is included into application like adding below in angular.json file

```
"styles": [
          "path/external.scss",
            "styles.scss"
        ],
```

I try to access some variables present in colors.scss file in my application but it says variable not found. I have to import the colors.scss file again inside my styles.scss file to detect the variable. Is there no way to prevent addition into styles.scss file.

Comment: In my case i have simply create `_vars.scss` and import in style.scss `@import "vars";` like that and in my `_vars.scss` code like `$BoxShadow: 0px 0px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);` and use in `style.scss` like `box-shadow: $BoxShadow`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `stylePreprocessorOptions` and specify an array of paths inside `includePaths`.