# Can't use SASS variables in Angular from global file, despite other styles working

Tags: css, angular, sass

When I apply the following SASS in my component's style, it works as supposed to.

```
$test-color: pink;
div{ background-color: $test-color; }
```

However, when I move the definition to *styles.scss*, it doesn't. I've tried adding the (now, [apparently](https://stefaniefluin.medium.com/the-new-sass-module-system-out-with-import-in-with-use-e1bd8ba032d0), deprecated) `@import "../styles.scss";` and also the currently recommended `@use "../styles.scss";`. I even tried to put the color definition in *colors.scss* and add that reference to *angular.json*. The styles for classes declared in *styles.scss* work (even without importing/using, due to it being references in the assets). But the variable, doesn't.

According to [this suggestion](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3700), it should work with `@include`. In [this docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables), it's shown how to assign the values. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68277741/1525840) linking to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66756104/1525840) but I can't see how that differs from my case. I tried to understand [this blog](https://css-tricks.com/introducing-sass-modules/) but couldn't see any relevant hints on what I'm doing wrong. I also tried adding the following (as shown [here](http://emilymikl.com/blog/sharing-scss-variables-in-angular/)).

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "src" ] }
```

I still get the error below, though.

> ERROR in ./src/app/.../some.component.scss
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: Undefined variable.
> 14 │     background-color: $test-color;
> ___   │ _________________                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
> src\app...\some.component.scss 14:23  root stylesheet

Googling the actual error gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61522703/1525840) saying that the variable isn't there. But as far I can tell, it is! A related, although a bit different, question was [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54308737/imports-from-external-styles-sheet-does-not-work-angular) but with no relevant answer.

What am I missing and how do I investigate it further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is due to wrong syntax as pointed out. It needs to reference the source of the colors.

```
background-color: colors.$test-color;
```

Furthermore, the import is required but needs to be done by reference to the module and not to the file.

```
@use "colors";
```

In a wholesome code base, one should put the following in the file *src\colors.scss*.

```
$test-color: pink;
```

Then you could use it like this.

```
@use "colors";
div{ background-color: colors.$test-color; }
```

In  the config file *angular.json*, the following needs to be set.

```
"styles": { ... },
"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "src" ] },
"scripts": { ... },
```

Also, it's should be noted that files prefixed by an underscore are subject to a different processing and as such, *_colors.scss* is preferred. While it's valid and working to place the auxiliary files directly in */src* (as is the case with *styles.scss*, the convention dictates to place them in */src/assets/styles*, altering the pre-processor's options as below.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": { "includePaths": [ "src/asses/styles" ] }
```

Comment: I'd like to keep your answer's contents as-is but I'll take the liberty to amend the precise change that was missing in my case (to align your answer to the question's exact formulation, while retaining the extra info that may come in handy for the future readers). I hope it's fine by you.

Comment: perfect, almost, yes, I tried to write "what works" and maybe skipped on details. Though regarding your modifications: IMO more specific value(s) in "includePath" should be preferred over just "src". Also _color.scss (not processed unless use/import) should be preferred over color.scss

Comment: Are you saying that the underscore in the file name actually implies a different process? I was not aware of that. Please confirm. Also, the path should be set according to the conventions, as not to surprise the next dude or dudess. I'll add both to the edit.

Comment: I see now how your code was correct from the start. However, when coming back to SASS'ing after a year of backend work, it seems easier to explain things step-by-step (at least in my opinion). Let me know if the latest edit erases the *almost* in your *perfect, almost, yes*.